# The following error occurred when I was compiling mediapipe

Tags: android, mediapipe

ERROR: /home/stone/.cache/bazel/_bazel_stone/daa4d9495d1d97556676d10ee33a3cad/external/maven/BUILD:468:11: Merging compiled Android resources for @maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_viewmodel failed (Exit 1): ResourceProcessorBusyBox failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-50AE0418/bin/external/bazel_tools/src/tools/android/java/com/google/devtools/build/android/ResourceProcessorBusyBox --tool MERGE_COMPILED -- --classJarOutput ... (remaining 11 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox ResourceProcessorBusyBox failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-50AE0418/bin/external/bazel_tools/src/tools/android/java/com/google/devtools/build/android/ResourceProcessorBusyBox --tool MERGE_COMPILED -- --classJarOutput ... (remaining 11 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Jul 02, 2021 10:21:11 AM com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledResourceMergingAction main
SEVERE: Unexpected
com.google.common.base.VerifyException: Unexpected magic number in generated/bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/maven/_aar/unzipped/resources/androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_viewmodel/res/values_empty.arsc.flat: 470425098
at com.google.common.base.Verify.verify(Verify.java:301)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.readResourceContainer(AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.java:719)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.read(AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.java:668)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.SerializedAndroidData.deserialize(SerializedAndroidData.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceMerger.mergeCompiledData(AndroidResourceMerger.java:258)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledResourceMergingAction.main(AndroidCompiledResourceMergingAction.java:231)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$3.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:81)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:233)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:177)

Jul 02, 2021 10:21:11 AM com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox processRequest
SEVERE: Error during processing
com.google.common.base.VerifyException: Unexpected magic number in generated/bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/maven/_aar/unzipped/resources/androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_viewmodel/res/values_empty.arsc.flat: 470425098
at com.google.common.base.Verify.verify(Verify.java:301)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.readResourceContainer(AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.java:719)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.read(AndroidCompiledDataDeserializer.java:668)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.SerializedAndroidData.deserialize(SerializedAndroidData.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidResourceMerger.mergeCompiledData(AndroidResourceMerger.java:258)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidCompiledResourceMergingAction.main(AndroidCompiledResourceMergingAction.java:231)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$3.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:81)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:233)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:177)